# How to load a Tensorflow graph created in a non-distributed environment to a distributed environment?

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed

I shall create a Tensorflow graph for a single node run. But later if I want to train the same model graph on a distributed environment (divide variables between multiple parameter servers and replicate the graph between n workers), how do I do it ?

I found something called [`tf.Graph.as_graph_def()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#as_graph_def) to export the GraphDef proto and later import the graph as [`tf.import_graph_def()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/import_graph_def). But this did not work.

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():
    x_place_holder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[], name="xin")
    y_place_holder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[], name="yin")

    m = tf.Variable(10.0, name="varm")
    l = tf.Variable(20.0, name="varl")

    Y = tf.multiply(m, x_place_holder, name="mulop")
    X = tf.add(l, x_place_holder, name="addop")
    cost = tf.abs(Y - X, name="cost")

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.5, name="optimizer").minimize(cost)

tf.reset_default_graph()

if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
    server.join()

elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":
    print(FLAGS.task_index, "task index")

    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
            worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
            cluster=cluster)):
        tf.import_graph_def(graph.as_graph_def(),return_elements=["xin","yin","varm","varl","mulop","addop","cost","optimizer"])
```

Stacktrace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1039, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1017, in _run_fn
    self._extend_graph()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1066, in _extend_graph
    self._session, graph_def.SerializeToString(), status)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot colocate nodes 'import/varl/read' and 'import/varl: Cannot merge devices with incompatible jobs: '/job:ps/task:1' and '/job:worker/task:1'
     [[Node: import/varl/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@import/varl"], _device="/job:worker/task:1"](import/varl)]]
```

Or is there any other way that Tensorflow allows to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not  supported as of june 2017. To train a model in a distributed environment you can reuse the graph-generating python code if it's wrapped in a replica_device_setter, but not the generated graph itself.